# select max id from current id mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the database.....

```
ID     Name     item_order     Manager
1      ted      2                N
2      bob      5                N
3      tony     1                Y
4      fred     3                N
5      william  4                N 
6      george   6                Y
7      cade     8                N
8      matt     7                N
```

I would like to be able to select managers Id prior to the current non managers name. So for example the result for bob would be tony or 3.

I can figure out how to do this with two requests

```
SELECT MAX( item_order) AS parent
FROM tablename WHERE item_order < 5 && Manager =  'Y'
```

The result from that I would make another select by the item_order. Is there a way to do this all in one select?

Comment: will u please explain more clearly?? exact what relation between `ID` and `item_order`?? write your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE Manager = 'Y'
AND item_order = (SELECT MAX(item_order) AS parent
                  FROM tablename 
                  WHERE item_order < 5 
                  AND Manager =  'Y') AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  n.*,
  ManagerName = m.Name
FROM tablename n
  LEFT JOIN tablename m ON m.Manager = 'Y' AND n.item_order > m.item_order
  LEFT JOIN tablename m2 ON m2.Manager = 'Y'
    AND m2.item_order < n.item_order AND m2.item_order > m.Item_order
WHERE n.Manager = 'N'
  AND m2.ID IS NULL
```

This will give you the list of all non-managers together with the names of those managers that directly precede them (based on `item_order`).

If you only want to return one row for a specific non-manager, add one more condition like this:

```
  AND n.Name = 'bob'
```